# Identifying RHEL8 version details

Tags: rhel8

I used to identify if the installed RHEL OS version was the "Server" or "Workstation" one in this way:

```
cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo)
```

Today, with RHEL8, I have this output:

```
cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.5 (Ootpa)
```

it looks like I have no chance to have the Server/Workstation detail.
How is this possible? How can I get the info I need out of it?

Answer (score 0):

[Is there any ISO for RHEL 8/9 Server or Workstation?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4203571)

***SOLUTION VERIFIED by Red Hat***- Updated March 24 2022 at 12:38 AM - English

***The same ISO for RHEL 8/9 can be utilized as a Server, Workstation or a Compute Node.***

***Environment***

Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8

Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9

***Issue***

Cannot find ISO of Server or Workstation for RHEL 8/9
Selecting 'Switch to Version 8' changes product variant from 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server' to 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux for x86_64' in the customer portal downloads page.

***Resolution***

Separate ISOs for Workstation or Server are ***NOT*** provided RHEL 8 onwards.
The offered variant for RHEL 8 is "Red Hat Enterprise Linux for x86_64".

You can make use of the 'System Purpose Role' to record the intended use of a Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 system i.e Server, Workstation or Compute node; however, using this feature is optional .

You can configure 'System Purpose' in one of the following ways:

- During image creation
- During a GUI installation when using the Connect to Red Hat screen to register your system and attach your Red Hat subscription
- During a Kickstart installation when using Kickstart automation scripts
- Post-installation only with the # syspurpose command-line tool.
  Possible components in System Purpose:

Role:

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Compute Node
Service Level Agreement:

Premium
Standard
Self-Support
Usage:

Production
Disaster Recovery
Development/Test
These components can be found on your RHEL 8 machine by running the following commands

`# cat /etc/rhsm/syspurpose/valid_fields.json`

Current set components:

`# syspurpose show`

***ROLE***

To Set the intended ROLE of the system: # syspurpose set-role 
Replace Value with the role that you want to assign:

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Compute Node
To Unset the ROLE : # syspurpose unset-role

***SLA***

To Set the intended SLA for the system:# syspurpose set-sla 
Replace Value with the Entitlement Support level that you want to assign:

Premium
Standard
Self-Support
To Unset the SLA : # syspurpose unset-sla

***USAGE***

To Set the intended USAGE of the system: # syspurpose set-usage 
Replace Value with the usage that you want to assign:

Production
Disaster Recovery
Development/Test
To Unset the USAGE: # syspurpose unset-usage

***Note:***
To know more about System Purpose you can check # man syspurpose or documentation at

- RHEL 8 6.6.5. Configuring system purpose.
- RHEL 9 12.3.5.1. Introduction to System Purpose

Root Cause
***The same ISO for RHEL 8/9 can be utilized as a Server, Workstation or a Compute Node.***